# Página em branco ao usar o ionic serve

Tags: ionic, ionic3

Quando executo o comando `ionic serve`, abre no navegador, porém abre como uma tela em branco. Isso sempre acontece quando executo esse comando a primeira vez.

Se eu pressionar as teclas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> o aplicativo aparece, funciona normal, porém as vezes a tela fica branca e fazendo o comando <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> volta a mostrar.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: viu se apresenta algum erro no console quando esse erro acontece?

Comment: quando eu digito ionic serve, abre a tela em branco, quando eu dou CTRL + SHIFT + I que abre o Console, a tela carrega. Informa isso no Console: http://prntscr.com/l9zv7f

Comment: docked ou floating? será que não é no resize da aba?

Comment: desculpe, estou iniciando na parte de desenvolvimento, docked ou floating, como faço para verificar? "será que não é no resize da aba?" então, eu pensei que fosse isso tbm, mas as vezes eu arrasto a janela do Console quando a tela fica branca mas mesmo assim não aparece, aí faço o comando e da certo, quer que eu te mande algum código?

Comment: Você deve estar usando um template blank tente executar ionic start nameApp sidemenu e depois rode o ionic serve. Coloque uma imagem de preferencia para que fique mais claro sua pergunta.